# SharePoint Online: Import data from excel to SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, import, excel-import

I have to upload data of excel columns to SharePoint list and the excel has got 8 to 9 sheets.
I tried copy paste every thing but is quite hectic.
Then I tried using **Import Excel Sheet** app but then its throws an error saying :

> "Unexpected Error has occurred".

Any suggestions with which I can do this with ease?

[image]

Comment: are you using google chrome!

Comment: Nope. I am using Internet Explorer.

Comment: Hi @Anand I have a very thorough and tested solution for exactly what you're looking for on a related question.
**Answer**: [Import/Copy/Paste Data from Excel into Existing SharePoint List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/224375/44163).

Comment: Which version of Office? Excel 2013 can able to upload to SharePoint 2013, but may not be compatible with SPO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this powershell script. You need to change some parameter.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/load-csv-file-value-into-sharepoint-list-using-powershell-script